# Why is conditionally using an empty panel in Apache Wicket a bad practice?

Tags: java, object-oriented, model

When Apache released its list of [best practices](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/6.x/guide/bestpractices.html#bestpractices_6), they recommended avoiding the addition of an empty panel conditionally and gave the following example of what NOT to do:

```
if(MySession.get().isNotLoggedIn()) {
    add(new LoginBoxPanel("login"))
}
else {
    add(new EmptyPanel("login"))
}
```

However, I see a lot of this type of code when I peer review, except it the second condition usually looks like this:

```
    add(new EmptyPanel("login")).setVisible(false);
```

The programmers justify code like this by saying they don't want to build the original component if it is not going to display.  That sounds like a logical argument to me.  Can someone explain what we are missing and why this is a bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a component conditionally is not safe. What if nothing is constructed because of the special conditions? (MarkupId not found exception..)
 In Wicket you should **avoid changes of the component tree**.
They say that it is wiser to **always generate the component and make it responsible of displaying itself**. This encapsulates business logic.
Also it is reusable, so you won't have the feeling that you have to be aware of duplicating the conditions part again and again.
Example of correct implementation:

```
public class YourComponent extends Component{

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean isVisible(){
        Boolean yourCondidtion;
        yourCondidtion = ...
        return yourCondidtion;
    }
};
```

or sometimes..

```
add(new YourComponent("id", ...)){
    @Override
    public boolean isVisible(){
       Boolean yourCondidtion;
       yourCondidtion = ...
       return yourCondidtion;
    }
};
```